# Kotlin nullable recursive generic boundary. How to?

Tags: kotlin, generics, recursion, nullable

I faced the problem trying to combine 3 concepts together in Kotlin: generics, generics with recursive boundary, nullable generic boundary. Here is a code:

```
class ClassA<T>(val field: T)

val OBJ1 = ClassA("1")
val OBJ2 = ClassA<String?>(null)
val OBJ3 = ClassA<String?>("3")

class ClassB<T: Comparable<T>>(val field: ClassA<T>) {
    companion object {
        val VALUES: Set<ClassB<*>> = setOf(ClassB(OBJ1), ClassB(OBJ2), ClassB(OBJ3))
    }
}
```

Expressions `ClassB(OBJ2)` and `ClassB(OBJ3)` can't be compiled, because `String? isn't a subtype of Comparable<String?>`

Does anyone know a workaround for this issue? I tried `T: Comparable<T?>`, `T: Comparable<T>?`, `T: Comparable<T?>?`. Neither of them worked for me.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me like just using a nullable type as an upper bound works: `T: Comparable<T>?`.

Comment: @hotkey I tried it. Doesn't work. Still see compile-time error in Idea.

Comment: That is not possible as you cannot simply compare a `String` to `null`. E.g. `"foo" < null` is not valid. If you explain a bit more what you'd like to achieve we could come up with alternative solutions. It's not clear from the current example.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the upper bound of `T` needs to be nullable to allow `T` to be nullable.

```
class ClassB<T: Comparable<T>?>(val field: ClassA<T>)
```

I think `String?` is not a subtype of `Comparable<String?>?` because `String` itself is not a subtype of `Comparable<String?>`. I don't know a way around this. That's how they defined the String class so you can't change it.

If you make a String wrapper class, it works:

```
class ClassA<T>(val field: T)

class String2(val value: String): Comparable<String2?> {
    override fun compareTo(other: String2?): Int {
        other ?: return 1
        return value.compareTo(other.x)
    }
}

val OBJ1 = ClassA(String2("1"))
val OBJ2 = ClassA<String2?>(null)
val OBJ3 = ClassA<String2?>(String2("3"))

class ClassB<T: Comparable<T>?>(val field: ClassA<T>) {
    companion object {
        val VALUES: Set<ClassB<*>> = setOf(ClassB(OBJ1), ClassB(OBJ2), ClassB(OBJ3))
    }
}
```